# Connecting USB Type C Flash Drive to Samsung Galaxy S9

Tags: samsung, external-sd, usb-drivers

Just bought the Kingston 64 GB DataTraveler microDuo 3C flash drive. The drive has both USB Type C and USB 3.1 port.

I tried connecting the drive directly via USB Type C port but it did not list the external storage. However when using the Samsung OTG it did recognize the drive.

The drive with dual port seems point less if the phone doesn't recognize the drive without OTG. Is this limited to only Samsung phones? Are there ways to connect the drive directly without the OTG? I have seen couple of videos on YouTube which reviewed the drive by connecting to phones without OTG. Thanks.

Comment: It should work. May be the Samsung does not recognize the filesystem the stick is formatted with (may be it is ExFAT formatted)? Use a PC and try FAT32 format just to test if it works.

Comment: It's very much possible as [shown here](Kingston 64 GB DataTraveler microDuo 3C flash drive) so it's likely format issue as suggested by @Robert. Try to reverse the direction of USB adapter and see (though it shouldn't matter)

Comment: Thanks both. As @Robert mentioned, it needs to be formatted to FAT32 for Samsung to recoginze the drive.